# Copying SharePoint 2010 farm to a different server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, server-farm, environment, replication

I am creating a replica server of my current SharePoint 2010 production server. The production SP is integrated with Project and TFS.

**Here is what I have done so far**:

- Installed SQL 2008, SharePoint 2010, Project, and TFS in a separate VM.
- Configured the SP base sites (Central Admin and Root).
- Backed up all the database from the production server.
- Restored the backups to the replica VM.

**Here is what I think I need to do next**:

- Mount the dbs individually to the root web app.
- Recreate each site collection separately so as to force it to use the attached db.
- ??

**Am I in the right direction**?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure patching/hotfix levels
2. Ensure Language packs required
3. Configure service applications.
4. Configure general farm settings.
5. Create and configure Web applications.
6. Reapply customizations (see the image below for type of customizations) , also check settings in Web.Config, SafeControls elements, GAC.
7. Attach the Content DBs to SQL server (ensure proper permissions for application pool account) and then to web applications by using PowerShell /CA.

**Important:**

For Production SharePoint, you should avoid installing Visual Studio, TFS or any development tool, a normal SP admin would kill you for that :). In other words, you just need a plain vanilla SharePoint installation, SQL box and of course OS.

For Acceptance SharePoint, **unless** you plan to do development on your acceptance environment you DON'T need to have Visual Studio and TFS on it.

For Development SharePoint, keep this box for all your SharePoint development experiments, dev tools (VS, TFS, and what not), build the packages (WSP) which would be deployable to any sane SP installation :)

For building each of above mentioned enviroment, you need to perform the above mentioned steps.

Happpy SharePointing!

[image]

Comment: fyi TFS is not a development tool like Visual Studio but a way to source control code. It is built on top of SharePoint so they do exist on the same server in production since TFS doesn't work without it.

Comment: TFS is a tool that has grown way beyond source control. It can surely be deployed to production to enter user stories, track progress, and run reports. But, SharePoint application development life cycle's core is to use automated TFS builds to perform automation with builds to QA and Production and generate TFS builds directly to those environments. But, performing SharePoint development on production is simply out of question, with and without source control; one must avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct [here is an article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd622870%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that goes through some more steps. The next step is applying all the customizations that were made. Things like

- Add any custom solutions (.wsps)
- Activate/Deactivate features
- Default quota templates
- etc...